# Offline Map Navigation

Tags: flutter, mapbox-gl

I was just wondering as to how to download/create a map out of Google Maps in order for it to work offline. I was thinking of creating a navigation system with offline Google Maps. As I could download the map using mapboxgl. I am having an issue regarding navigation in offline map.

How can we achieve offline map navigation in flutter?

Comment: Looking for the same. I want to implement offline navigation and tracking and want to know the complete process of it.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/flutter-mapbox-gl/maps you will find this helpful to you.